# Typeorm, how to handle deleted entities when running migrations

Tags: typescript, migration, typeorm

My project has a refactor where an entity is removed however, when I attempt to run a new migration via `typeorm migration:run` I get typescript errors from my initial migrations (ones already ran) because I no longer have the entity it's importing.

```
src/migrations/1603278044988-defaultEntity.ts:3:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../entities/entity' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import Entity from '../entities/entity';
```

Meanwhile `src/migrations/1603278044988-defaultEntity.ts` was run and registered in my db some time ago.

My initial feeling was to exclude my migrations directly in my tsconfig but this does not result in anything different it seems. I'm also not seeing a way to run the migrations without the ts check or isolating the one migration file.

`TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE` is `False`

Answer (score 1):

I realize the previous migrations should not be using any "source" code and they should be replaced with raw inserts.

Worst case, rather than deleting the entities I can move them inline into the migrations or as an import specifically for them.